# Can I set the height and width of a view with percentage of screen?

Tags: android

I would like to know if setting the size with a percentage is possible without using third-party libraries.

Example

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="70%"
    android:layout_height="80%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Android Constraint Layout you can specify [Percentage](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#percent-dimension) sizes